# For TTY, Command vs `echo command | bash`

Tags: bash, docker, shell, tty

It worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
docker exec -it pure-ftpd ftp localhost
printenv
```

It failed, because of **"the input device is not a TTY"**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
{
  echo "docker exec -it pure-ftpd ftp localhost"
} | {
  bash
  printenv
}
```

And environment variables of two scripts are same. Can someone tell me what is the difference? And [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/install) use pipelines(2nd way) to run the script, when should not use pipelines?

Comment: maybe you could use `bash -c` or `xargs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what is the difference?

The difference is the input to `docker exec`.

```
docker exec ... - input is your keyboard
```

and:

```
{
    echo docker exec ...  - your keyboard is ignored, echo does not read from stdin
} | {
     bash  - The input comes _only_ from echo, which is captured by bash.
}
```

Because you requested an interactive TTY `-ti` and because there is no more input (let's say "your keyboard is ignored"), there is nothing for `docker exec -ti` to do.